# In Python for loop, how to create legends for plots?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have successfully created a figure of four sub-plots and two of subplots having double y-axis features as shown below. Each subplot has many different plots. I wanted to add a legend. But, I could not do it with code. The figure is given below:

[image]

My code is given below:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(17,10))
fig.legend(loc="center right", fontsize=13,fancybox=True, framealpha=1, shadow=True, borderpad=1)    
plt.rc('font',family='Times New Roman')
.
.
for i,j in zip(IV_start_index,IV_start_index[1:]):  # This is simple code to access present and next element in a list    
    axs[0][0].plot(module_allData_df['Time'].iloc[mpp_index],pmpp_theo,'bs',label="Theoretical")
    axs[0][0].plot(module_allData_df['Time'].iloc[mpp_index],pmpp_act,'rd',label="Actual")
    .  
    .  
    plt.suptitle('A NIST Module %s power loss analysis'%(module_allData_df['Time'].loc[i].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')),fontsize=18) # 
    plt.savefig('All_day_power_loss')
```

The output is:

```
No handles with labels found to put in legend.
```

Could you help me to correct my code?

Corrections: 
I did change the code as given below.

```
for i,j in zip(IV_start_index,IV_start_index[1:]):  # This is simple code to access present and next element in a list    
        axs[0][0].plot(module_allData_df['Time'].iloc[mpp_index],pmpp_theo,'bs',label="Theoretical")
        axs[0][0].plot(module_allData_df['Time'].iloc[mpp_index],pmpp_act,'rd',label="Actual")
        axs[0][0].legend()
```

It has created many legends.The output figure is given below:

[image]

Comment: This link [matplotlib legend handles](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html) has the solution. You have to add handles to your legends.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you don't provide the legend entries within the `legend()` function, it should be placed *after* the `label`-entries in the plot commands. Otherwise `legend` cannot know what to list.
2. If you want to have a legend within each subplot, you should call `axs[i][j].legend()` within a loop (or call `axs[0][0].legend()`, `axs[0][1].legend()`, ... manually for each subplot of course). The point is: `fig.legend()` is a legend on *figure level*, i.e. one legend for all subplots together. This should be called once outside of the loop.

Comment: I have modified my code and response is given in my above question. But, it created a many legends.

Comment: `axs[0][0]` is your upper left subplot. if you want a legend in another subplot, you should change the indices, i.e. `axs[0][1].legend()` puts a legend in the next subplot and so on. if you repeatedly call `legend` on the same subplot again and again, it will produce a legend there again and again leading to far too many entries.

Comment: In my above question, I have uploaded the latest figure which is obtained after adding `axs[0][0].legend()`. Did you observe, my first subplot ? See the legend. It just repeated for 100 times as `for` loop iterates. Any way out?

Comment: I'm not sure what your loop iterates over, but you somehow should have plotting commands for the several subplots, otherwise there wouldn't be any plots in all the subplots. For legends it's the same thing, call legend on every subplot, either one after another manually or in a loop. If this loop iterates 100 times, obviously this is the wrong one for legend... :-)

Comment: Additionally, your way to plot seems to call plot _plus its label-keyword_ 100 times. This also will produce a separate legend entry for each call of plot... We should have closer look on how your data is structured and if the plotting could be mad more efficient, i.e. is one call of `plot`. Otherwise, you'd have to programmatically control, that the label keyword is only active once per 100 iterations, i.e. per subplot...

Comment: This link has the solution. You have to add handles to your legends.
[matplotlib legend handles](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html)

Answer (score 1):

After a series of trails, I did the following to my code:

```
for i,j in zip(IV_start_index,IV_start_index[1:]):  # This is simple code to access present and next element in a list    
    axs[0][0].plot(module_allData_df['Time'].iloc[mpp_index],pmpp_theo,'bs')
    axs[0][0].plot(module_allData_df['Time'].iloc[mpp_index],pmpp_act,'rd')
    axs[0][0].legend(['Theoretical','Actual'])
    .
    .
```

My output is:

[image]

Comment: Youput a legend command in a loop which iterates 100 times - this is not correct. In your above code you addtionally have title generation and savefig to save the figure to a file in the same loop. You should overthink which parts of your code belong to which context - Do you want to write the same title and your file 100 times? Probably not. IMHO the problem here lies even a bit deeper: you plot every single point of your data separately - that's why you have this loop. This is inefficient. This stuff is makeable by only one or a few lines. Please post `module_allData_df.head()` as text